# How do I test WINE?

Tags: wine

I found an instructible for using SketchUp in Ubuntu that requires using WINE.  I supposedly loaded the wine program, but I can't find it.

If I do find it, I still would like to test to see if it is installed correctly.  Anybody have any ideas?

first: where do I look to see if it was downloaded?

second: how do I test it?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Test wine by launch notepad.exe

```
wine notepad.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

You run wine from the command line. Some applications will be added to your menu, but in my experience it is a bit of hit and miss.

You next need to install your application, SketchUp . You need to installation file, SketchUp.exe

```
wine /home/your_user/SketchUp.exe
```

Not sure if after you install SketchUp will be in your menu (it might) under the wine glass symbol or SketchUp, or if not wine /path/to/installedSketchUp , usually in ~/.wine in the c_drive.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine

Comment: When I go to command line and type wine it says the program is not loaded.  Then it says I need to type "xxx" to do so.  I copy and paste and enter and it then says I need another thingy, so I copy and paste again.  Then I do the wine load again, and it eventually shows a Windows permission statement that allows no response.  So I go to command prompt again and type wine and it says the program isn't loaded.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post yourr exact command and the error message

Comment: when I type "wine" it says "The program wine is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install wine1.6-i386
so I do that.  I provide my password.  It then says          you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. I do that.  It appears to run but only a new command line comes up.  I then re-paste sudo apt-get install wine1.6-i386 and enter.  It says After this operation, 207 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] and I respond with Y. I then get a blue screen with Configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Comment: This is on a blue screen and seems to ask for an OK, but there is nothing to click on and the operation seems dead.

Comment: At the blue screen, use the tab key to navigate to the yes or ok, then hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look in the Ubuntu Software Center or Synaptic to see if you installed the WINE packages correctly. They're available from the regular Ubuntu sources/repositories, and when I installed them they always added WINE menu items to the "start menu". I'm not sure if you're using Unity or MATE or XFCE or K, but there should be some graphic way to look through your program shortcuts.

If the guide you followed involved downloading mystery files from mystery websites to install wine, that's not the usual linux/Ubuntu way to install programs. The usual way is to use apt (probably the "xxx" command you mentioned in a comment?) or a graphic front-end like Ubuntu Software Center or Synaptic. They should take care of the dependencies for a program install automatically.